# Having trouble using COUNT with INTERSECT in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to run the code below in Teradata. However, I keep getting an error when I try to count the number of rows this intersection has. The error is: Failed [2616 : 22003] Numeric overflow occurred during computation.

I tried using a CAST with BIGINT, but now the value comes empty. When I run the actual intersect (without the COUNT clause) - I am able to see the list of rows of this intersect. I want to be able to count this number. Do you know how I can do this?

```
select CAST(count(a.main_id) AS BIGINT) from second_database.tra_rock a
    database.game_active b ON a.main_key=b.main_key AND description_detail LIKE 'AC'
    database.release_day c ON a.release_key = c.release_key AND g_description = 'FW'
    database.ft_feature d on a.main_id = d.main_id AND first_time >= 20200319 
    where action_date_key between 20200319 and 20200324 and a.main_id IN 
        (select a.main_id
        From second_database.tra_rock a
        database.game_active b ON a.main_key=b.main_key AND description_detail LIKE 'AC'
        where action_date > 20200324 and release_key = 200)
    INTERSECT
    select a.main_id
    From second_database.tra_rock a
    database.game_active b ON a.main_key=b.main_key AND description_detail LIKE 'AC'
    database.release_day c ON a.release_key = c.release_key AND g_description = 'FW'
    database.ft_feature d on a.main_id = d.main_id AND DATE_KEY >= 20200319 
    where action_date_key between 20200319 and 20200324 and a.main_id IN 
        (select a.main_id
        From second_database.tra_rock a
        database.game_active b ON a.genome_key=b.genome_key AND description_detail <> 'AC'
        where action_date > 20200324 and release_key = 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT is applied to the first Select only and then you try to Intersect the counts and the main_id from the second Select.

You need to wrap the full query into a Derived Table or a Common Table Expression:

```
select cast(count(*) as bigint)
from
 ( 
    select a.main_id from second_database.tra_rock a
        database.game_active b ON a.main_key=b.main_key AND description_detail LIKE 'AC'
        database.release_day c ON a.release_key = c.release_key AND g_description = 'FW'
        database.ft_feature d on a.main_id = d.main_id AND first_time >= 20200319 
        where action_date_key between 20200319 and 20200324 and a.main_id IN 
            (select a.main_id
            From second_database.tra_rock a
            database.game_active b ON a.main_key=b.main_key AND description_detail LIKE 'AC'
            where action_date > 20200324 and release_key = 200)
        INTERSECT
        select a.main_id
        From second_database.tra_rock a
        database.game_active b ON a.main_key=b.main_key AND description_detail LIKE 'AC'
        database.release_day c ON a.release_key = c.release_key AND g_description = 'FW'
        database.ft_feature d on a.main_id = d.main_id AND DATE_KEY >= 20200319 
        where action_date_key between 20200319 and 20200324 and a.main_id IN 
            (select a.main_id
            From second_database.tra_rock a
            database.game_active b ON a.genome_key=b.genome_key AND description_detail <> 'AC'
            where action_date > 20200324 and release_key = 200)
 ) as dt
```

Comment: @Charlie - please go back to all of your questions ans=d accept answers plus up-vote them . I see you never accepted any answer on your questions. thank you